# Sharing folder with external visitors via Google Drive API

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

Any ideas on how to share a Google drive folder with an external visitor that does not have a Gmail address?

When creating link(Using UI) for external visitor(not a gmail or gdrive user) we get an option to notify user with a link(This is not the same link as share link).

> The notification email contains a link where user visits and enters an
> OTP to login which is emailed to external user by Google.

I need the external user to have writer access too. I can see [here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/9195194#zippy=%2Cfile-types-you-can-share-with-a-non-google-domain) that it is possible via the UI however I cannot find any reference to this in the API documentation. I have successfully generated a share link using this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-sharing), but Google is requiring the user to log in, which is not what I want.

Comment: You might want to check this [here](https://support.google.com/a/thread/10729987/i-cannot-get-my-google-drive-folder-to-share-with-anyone-with-a-link-option?hl=en&msgid=10756779) - can you confirm in this situation that the settings for your domain are set accordingly in order to share it with a non-Google account?

Comment: Thanks @ale13. 

For anybody experiencing a similar issue, users can access the folder without a gmail address, but they will have to go through a signup process where they use a third party email address. The only way to give access to users without them having the need to sign-up to Google is by sharing a public link to the folder.